# Node Exporter - Specific collector scrape_interval

Tags: prometheus, grafana, prometheus-node-exporter

I have been scraping the internet trying to find a way to set specific scrape_interval for specific collectors. For example, I want all of my collectors from node exporter to have a scrape_interval of 1m so I won’t overpopulate my prometheus and this way I can keep a reasonable amount of active series, but when having a scrape_interval of 1m, the metrics of cpu stops working, since they need more datapoints. So I want specifically to set scrape_interval of cpu to 15s and the rest for 1m.

How can I achieve something like this?
Thanks a bunch,
Have a good day :)

```
server:
  http_listen_port: 12345
prometheus:
  wal_directory: /tmp/grafana-agent-wal
  global:
    scrape_interval: 45s
  configs: null
integrations:
  node_exporter:
    enabled: true
    set_collectors:
    - cpu
    - cpufreq
    - devstat
    - diskstats
    - filesystem
    - loadavg
    - meminfo
    - netclass
    - netdev
    - netstat
    - processes
    - vmstat
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the global config scrape_interval:

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 1m
```

And use the job config scrape_interval for the specific collector:

```
scrape_configs:
  job_name: <job_name>
    scrape_interval: 15s
```

Comment: I am using the grafana exporter, this config is not valid there. Maybe I'm missing something, can you specify the exact configuration and the level it sits on?

Comment: I edited my question containing the configuration file I have right now

Comment: So, you're not using Prometheus, correct?

Comment: It is grafana's agent which uses the prometheus node_exporter